# how to find all values of corresponding search value in excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have one problem.

using c# is it possible to find values using id.i read excel file and searching value using `if (id == excelSheet1.Cells[j, 1].Value)` in loop.
It checks all records,if matching found, returns value and comes out of the loop.

```
int id=101;
```

is it possible to find value in faster method like `excel.contains(id)`?
my code uses linear search method, it's time consuming.

please help me.

Comment: There's no other way. It *shouldn't* be slow either, unless you use Interop, resulting in a cross-process call for each method call or property get. If you use Interop you can use Excel's own search functionality, eg use Range.Find. If not, eg if you use EPPlus or the OpenXML SDK,  searching should be fast

Comment: ok, thanks for your information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for My question.Thank you  mendy.

```
       string id = "OZHAN1";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range resultRange = excelRange.Find(

        What: id,

        LookIn: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,

        LookAt: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,

        SearchOrder: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,

        SearchDirection: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext

        );
        string sAddress = resultRange.get_Address(false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, false, false);
        string b= excelSheet.Cells[resultRange.Row, 5].VALUE;
```

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: @Arya, thank you for above code, now that we found the specific value, how can we store the data of that row in which the value is into an array or soemthing?

so if lets say cell J3 has the id, I want to take that entire row and store it in an array. Thank you for you expertise  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you'll store the data in DataTable you can use Select() method and find all rows by a query (like `DataRow[] matches dt.Select("ID = " + id);`).

In my experience it's pretty fast, but I've never checked it on a very large tables (I've mostly checked it on tables containing between 10,000-15,000 records).

Comment: i'm using excel, searching particular id.

Comment: how exactly do you read the excel file? can you post the code?

Comment: Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(GeoUserFile);
            _Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
            Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

            int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;

Comment: in loop id==excelSheet.Cells[i, 8].Value then remaining work. Its time consuming

Comment: maybe excelSheet.Columns[8].Find(id)

Comment: if value fetch, how to get corresponding other values?